# How to make multiple Popovers in one id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popper.js

Could I make a lot of popovers with one ID?

```
<div class="card-text">
   <a href="#" id="seelabel" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="Inkscape" data-content="Lihat postingan dengan label Inkscape?"><span class="badge badge-primary" id="Inkscape">Inkscape</span></a>
</div>
<div class="card-text">
   <a href="#" id="seelabel" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="Tutorial" data-content="Lihat postingan dengan label Tutorial?"><span class="badge badge-primary" id="Inkscape">Inkscape</span></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#seelabel').popover({
  trigger: 'hover'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id attribute should be unique (you can't have more than one element with the same id).

Try instead of `id="seelabel"`,   `class="seelabel"` and in your javascript:

```
$('.seelabel').popover({
  trigger: 'hover'
})
```

Comment: Thanks, its work. Why I did not think of it, even though the bootstrap page has been explained.